# How can I have non-breaking-spaces show differently in terminal?

Tags: reactjs, bash, shell, stdout

I recently spent too many hours debugging a simple string comparison in React, the issue was that one string had a space, and the other had a non-breaking-space. When I did a console.log, the output in the terminal looked identical.

Is there a terminal setting or a product I can use so `&nbsp;` would look different to a normal space?

Note: Running on windows.

Comment: Do you have bash and posix shell on windows? Why did you tag them? Do you want to view the output in a terminal?

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) I have bash shell on Windows and yes, I'm wanting to view the output in a terminal.

Comment: Then just [`cat`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cat.html) the file. The `&nbsp;` will be visible as 5 characters.

Comment: It took me some time to work out that a `&nbsp;` was the issue. Ideally I would be able to tell just by the display from console.log to stdout.